# Nodejs App working fine Locally but when launched online its having issue

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs application below. when I run it locally, its working fine.

This is how I run the app locally and it works fine. At prompt

```
$ export CLIENT_ID=<your_client_id>
$ export CLIENT_SECRET=<your_client_secret>
$ export CALLBACK_URL="call-back-url-goes-here"
$ node app.js
```

Now I need to test the app online at two different places

1.) At **mysite**

2.) At **glitches.com**

Note that In mysite all other the nodejs application is running perfect because am using **PM2** to start or stop nodejs applications

Okay this is how I run this app on mysite and it works as long as the Command shell(putty) is still on but if close the prompt(putty), all this exported variables (Client_id, client_secret, callback_url) will be lost or becomes undefined

```
$ export CLIENT_ID=<your_client_id>
    $ export CLIENT_SECRET=<your_client_secret>
    $ export CALLBACK_URL="call-back-url-goes-here"
    $ pm2 start app.js
```

What could be a solution to this. Is there any way that I can integrated all this export variables **(Client_id, client_secret, callback_url)** into **app.js** applications so that I can just use pm2 to start my nodejs app as usual or is there any other approach to this.  I also plan to test it at **glitches.com**.
Can someone help me resolve this.

Below is the code Thanks

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const gMore = require('gMore-node');

const app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');


app.use(session({
  secret: 'YOURSECRET',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000
  }
}));

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
 const scope = 'report:data_to_fetch';

  const authorizeUrl = genomeLink.OAuth.authorizeUrl({ scope: scope });

  // Fetching a protected resource using an OAuth2 token if exists.
  let reports = [];
  if (req.session.oauthToken) {
    const scopes = scope.split(' ');
    reports = await Promise.all(scopes.map( async (name) => {
      return await gMore.Report.fetch({
        name: name.replace(/report:/g, ''),
        population: 'european',
        token: req.session.oauthToken
      });
    }));
  }

  res.render('index.html', {
    authorize_url: authorizeUrl,
    reports: reports,
  });
});

app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
  req.session.oauthToken = await gMore.OAuth.token({ requestUrl: req.url });
  res.redirect('/');
});

// I can change the port on production 3000
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server running at http://mysite:' + port + '/');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check out npm  `dotenv`.  You place all your environment specific information in there, rather than explicitly needing to type in your own shell variables.
2. Closing putty means you're closing your connection.  If this action is killing pm2, it's likely that pm2 is running in the foreground, and upon connection close, it's terminating that process.  Is your pm2 daemon running?  It "should" be default be and executing `pm2 start app.js` should return immediate control to the command line.
   Also I'd recommend using a `pm2ecosystem.json` file as your start file.